# Finding an angle on a quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the 4 angles that are circled in the image. I need to make these cuts, but don't know how to find the angle. Any help is appreciated. :)

[image: http://www.hawns.com/angle.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt: Check out the picture
[image]

The horizontal blue segment is $$13\  1/2\!\!" - 7\  7/16\!\!" = 6 \ 1/16\!\!"$$

and so the tangent of the lower red angle, call it $\phi$ is

$$\tan (\phi) = \frac{ 52}{\frac{97}{16}}= \frac{832}{97}$$

and so 
$$\phi = \arctan(\frac{832}{97})\, \text{rad}=   \arctan(\frac{832}{97})\cdot \frac{180}{\pi} ^{\circ}= 83.3501^{\circ}$$

and so the upper red angle is 
$$180^{\circ} - 83.3501^{\circ}=96.6499^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 1):

let the base acute be $x,$ the $tan x = \dfrac{52*16}{97}$ or $x =\arctan(832/97)$ and upper angles are $180^\circ - x$